# Avoid blas when involving temporary memory allocation?

Tags: c++, performance, linear-algebra, blas, intel-mkl

I have a program that computes the matrix product `x'Ay` repeatedly.  Is it better practice to compute this by making calls to MKL's blas, i.e. `cblas_dgemv` and `cblas_ddot`, which requires allocating memory to a temporary vector, or is better to simply take the sum of `x_i * a_ij * y_j`?  In other words, does MKL's blas theoretically add any value?

I benchmarked this for my laptop.  There was virtually no difference in each of the tests, other than g++_no_blas performed twice as poorly as the other tests (why?).  There was also no difference between O2, O3 and Ofast.

1. g++_blas_static 57ms
2. g++_blas_dynamic 58ms
3. g++_no_blas 100ms
4. icpc_blas_static 57ms
5. icpc_blas_dynamic 58ms
6. icpc_no_blas 58ms

**util.h**

```
#ifndef UTIL_H
#define UTIL_H

#include <random>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct rng 
{
        rng() : unif(0.0, 1.0)
        {
        }

        std::default_random_engine re; 
        std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif;

        double rand_double()
        {
                return unif(re);
        }

        std::unique_ptr<double[]> generate_square_matrix(const unsigned N)
        {
                std::unique_ptr<double[]> p (new double[N * N]);
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                {
                        for (unsigned j = 0; j < N; ++j)
                        {
                                p.get()[i*N + j] = rand_double();
                        }
                }
                return p;
        }

        std::unique_ptr<double[]> generate_vector(const unsigned N)
        {
                std::unique_ptr<double[]> p (new double[N]);
                for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; ++i)
                {
                        p.get()[i] = rand_double();
                }
                return p;
        }
};

#endif // UTIL_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include "util.h"
#include "mkl.h"

double vtmv_blas(double* x, double* A, double* y, const unsigned n)
{
        double temp[n];
        cblas_dgemv(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, n, n, 1.0, A, n, y, 1, 0.0, temp, 1); 
        return cblas_ddot(n, temp, 1, x, 1); 
}

double vtmv_non_blas(double* x, double* A, double* y, const unsigned n)
{
        double r = 0;
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
                for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                {
                        r += x[i] * A[i*n + j] * y[j];
                }
        }
        return r;
}

int main()
{
        std::cout << std::fixed;
        std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
        constexpr unsigned N = 10000;
        rng r;

        std::unique_ptr<double[]> A = r.generate_square_matrix(N);
        std::unique_ptr<double[]> x = r.generate_vector(N);
        std::unique_ptr<double[]> y = r.generate_vector(N);

        auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        const double prod = vtmv_blas(x.get(), A.get(), y.get(), N); 
        auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                end - start);

        std::cout << "Result: " << prod << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time (ms): " << duration.count() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC no blas is poor because it does not use vectorized SMID instructions, while others all do. icpc will auto-vectorize you loop.

You don't show your matrix size, but generally gemv is memory bound. As the matrix is much larger than a temp vector, eliminating it may not be able to increase the performance a lot.